# Getting list of values from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet on which I have created a list consisting of many values. Also I have created a macro which shows a userform in which those values are hard-coded.

Now I want that those values in the form to be automatically/programatically/dynamically added to my userform list, so that in the future, if I want to decrease the values from the list, then I would not have to change the macro again.

I have been searching for the answer but I have been unsuccessful in finding what I am looking for.

I have recorded this macro, but I don't know how to retrieve values from it:

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$175").AutoFilter Field:=5
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this list in the Userform an Array? or in a ComboBox? or a  Listbox? or something else?

Comment: The values I want to get in excel cell is in the form of list. and has a filter enabled. and i want to add those values in user form list box.

Comment: Before I give you the code, maybe you would like to try yourself by looping through the list in the worksheet and then using  `ListBox1.Add` to add the new items?

Comment: I have updated the code. @Siddharth Rout

Comment: You are filtering it on what criteria?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541186/copying-all-the-visible-rows-in-the-current-sheet-and-pasting-it-to-another-shee/11543074#11543074 on how to use autofilter :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually that list has some countries in it. and we can select multiple countries as well. so if some countries are selected than sheet filters some data. for now i have no concern how it filters i just want to get all the available countries values from that list.

Comment: here is a link of my sample sheet http://www.speedyshare.com/qneTe/sample.xlsx

I just want to get the list of values from E1 cell. so that i can load it into the list box of the user form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro you've specified will turn on autofiltering for your active worksheet.  This will provide column headers that will allow the user to filter to something of interest.
Assuming that this kind of filtering of the worksheet is what you want, you can use something like:

```
Dim r As Range
'Note: set r to something useful, such as worksheet.Cells

Dim vis As Range
Set vis = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'now vis holds a special "Range" object referring to the visible cells.
'since (auto) filtering hides some cells, this vis range will help show only the cells that remain visible.
'the output of SpecialCells, you should assume holds a complex Range,
'which is composed of multiple Areas that are wrapped in one single Range object
'the separate areas help you distinguish the visible cells from the hidden cells
'fyi, various safety checks you can do: vis Is Range, vis Is Nothing

Dim a as Areas
Set a = r.Areas

Dim cr as Range
For Each cr in a
    'cr refers to a single (i.e. normal and contiguous) area range
    'where you can use cr.Row, cr.Column, cr.Rows.Count, cr.Columns.Count
Next
```

So when you do filtering, you can use SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to reveal the non-hidden cells, which are represented as have a range that wraps areas that represent contiguous ranges.

Answer (score 0):

With a userform named UReports that has a listbox named lbxReport, use code like this to fill the listbox with values from column E

```
Sub ShowUf()

    Dim ufReports As UReports
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim colUnique As Collection
    Dim i As Long

    Set ufReports = New UReports
    Set colUnique = New Collection

    'loop through the cells in column E
    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("E2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Cells
        'Collections can't have duplicate keys, so we try to add all the values.  If there
        'are duplicates, the 'On Error' ignores them and we're left with a collection of
        'only unique values from column E
        On Error Resume Next
            colUnique.Add rCell.Value, CStr(rCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next rCell

    'loop through the collection and add them to the listbox
    For i = 1 To colUnique.Count
        ufReports.lbxReport.AddItem colUnique.Item(i)
    Next i

    'Show the form
    ufReports.Show

End Sub
```